# Creating a file causing crashes android

Tags: android

I am trying to create a function that downloads a pdf and saves it, I am using the following code.

```
public class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String fileUrl = strings[0];   // -> http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/maven.pdf
        String fileName = strings[1];  // -> maven.pdf
        String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "testthreepdf");
        folder.mkdir();

        File pdfFile = new File(folder, fileName);

        try{
            pdfFile.createNewFile();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        FileDownloader.downloadFile(fileUrl, pdfFile);
        return null;
    }
}
```

It works fine about 60% of the time but sometimes on the line:

```
File pdfFile = new File(folder, fileName);
```

It crashes the app, when I try again it then works.  The error it throws is not that helpful

An error occurred while executing `doInBackground()`

Stacktrace:

```
08-17 15:08:48.097 27281-27317/com.heyjude.heyjudeapp W/System.err: mkdir failed: EEXIST (File exists) : /storage/emulated/0/testthreepdf
08-17 15:09:36.807 27281-27311/com.heyjude.heyjudeapp I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
08-17 15:09:36.847 27281-27311/com.heyjude.heyjudeapp I/System.out: KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
08-17 15:09:36.877 27281-27311/com.heyjude.heyjudeapp I/System.out: KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
```

Comment: Please provide a stacktrace of the crash

Comment: also your manifest

Comment: Sorry for nooby questions
1.  Is stacktrace what android monitor spits out after the crash?
2.  what is manifest?

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Why would that file be relevant to this question?

Comment: `An error occured while executing doInBackground()`. There will be more in the LogCat. Post it.

Comment: i just edited does that help?

Comment: `folder.mkdir();`. Check the return value. If it returns false you should not continue with the code but return. Better care for directories before you call that task.

Comment: `pdfFile.createNewFile();` Dont do that. the downloadFile function will care for it. Ant if you keep it and there is no catch you can delete the file right away. And if there is a catch you should not continue with the code but return and inform the user.

Comment: `mkdir failed: EEXIST (File exists) : /storage/emulated/0/testthreepdf 08-17 15:09:36.807 ` . So do not call mkdir() if the directory already exists. (Mmmm... @EJP did you see this message before? ), but check with `folder.exists()` if it is already there.

Comment: thanks for the tips so far.  

So i must check if the file exists and if it does not exists I do not need to run File pdfFile = new File(folder, fileName);

However that creates a new problem as I need pdfFile to run this line

        FileDownloader.downloadFile(fileUrl, pdfFile);